# p value for difference in model outcomes

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, model, model-comparison

I've run two different linear mixed effects models on the same data and got two different estimates for the gradient of the longitudinal variable. e.g.

model 1 has estimate 30 with standard error 5.
model 2 has estimate 40 with standard error 4.

I'm interested in calculating a p value for the probability that the models are different, from the estimate and standard error. How do I do this? I'm aware that checking for overlap in the 95% confidence intervals is a bad idea, and that overlapping 83% CIs are a better test, but would like to be able to quantify this with a p value.

Comment: [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) might be more appropriate for comparing the two models.

Comment: AIC makes a very different kind of comparison to the kind of comparison I'm looking to make. Whether a test is appropriate is dependant on the question you're actually trying to answer with the test. I'm looking for a way to compare how different the estimates are, rather than compare model quality.

Comment: To clarify what you're attempting: When you say you've run two different models, do you mean that you have fitted two models with different terms, e.g. as a simple example for response variable y, and explanatory variables x, z and v, did you fit models y = a.x + b.z + c as opposed to y = l.x + m.v + e, and now you want to compare coefficients a and l? Or have you parameterised a model twice with the same terms (e.g. y = a.x + b.z + c but presumably something more complicated) using different fitting processes each time, and you now want to compare your two estimates of a?

Comment: I suggest you try to formulate what null hypothesis you're actually trying to test.

Comment: @Izy the latter is correct. Model with the same terms, one more complicated. The null hypothesis is that both of the estimates are the same. I have 95% confidence intervals / standard errors. It's pretty easy to determine if the estimate is significantly different to a number, based on whether the confidence intervals spans the number. But having trouble finding a source for a method where there is a CI / Std. Err. around both of the things you're comparing

Comment: Is a simulation out of the question?

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt yeah, and seems over the top. I have the 95% confidence intervals. It's easy to tell if the result is significantly different from a specified number. Surely there must be a generalisation of this to overlapping CIs?

Comment: So you had additional terms in your second model? e.g. you fitted one model y = a.x + b.z + c, and a second model y= l.x + m.z + p.v + e?
I use different letters for coefficients 'a' and 'l' because I would expect a model with an additional term to have different coefficients for a variable used in both models. In this case I am not clear on why it would be relevant to compare the values 'a', and 'l': the comparison that @Ben - Reinstate Monica describes seems to be the most relevant null hypothesis to test. Examining the covariance matrix would give further insight.

Comment: your model estimates *are* different, you know that. what do you want to test?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question how these models relate to one another.  However, the way you perform a statistical test for equivalence of models is to pose them as *nested models* and then perform a statistical test to see whether the additional terms in the more complex model are "zero".  For example, suppose you have two linear models like this:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Simple Model} & & y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,i} + \cdots \beta_k x_{k,i} + \epsilon_i, 
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \\[6pt]
\text{Complex Model} & & y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,i} + \cdots \beta_k x_{k,i} + \beta_{k+1} x_{k+1,i} + \cdots \beta_{k+m} x_{k+m,i} + \varepsilon_i. \\[6pt]
\end{matrix}$$

This is an example where your simple model is "nested" within your more complex model.  You can test the equivalence by testing the hypotheses:

$$H_0: \beta_{k+1} = \cdots = \beta_{k+m} = 0
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
H_A: H_0 \text{ is false}.$$

The null hypothesis here reduces the complex model to the simple model, which is equivalent to saying that the models are really the same.  Using a classical hypothesis test we can see if there is evidence to reject the null hypothesis that both models are the same.